# Openshift scheduler Affinity

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a openshift cluster and want my pods when scaled more than 1 to end up on different nodes based on zone label. For example half of my nodes have zone=EU and another half zone=US. Every time I scale up pods to 2 they are beinf placed little random, sometimes end up on US,US sometimes EU,US and EU,EU.

What I want is always to be EU,US or US,EU.

I use default /etc/origin/master/scheduler.json which  at the bottom has this

```
        "argument": {
            "serviceAntiAffinity": {
                "label": "zone"
            }
        },
        "name": "Zone",
        "weight": 2
    }
]
```

Any ideas how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pod anti-affinity.](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/admin_guide/scheduling/pod_affinity.html#admin-guide-sched-affinity-pod-config)
You may try to use `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`  and try to create rules for distributing your pods.

Comment: Hi. I have no control over the pods, they are more than a 1000. For me to control all the pods and have them configure affinity/antiaffinity is impossible. They are created and maintained by other users , they might use templates or create DC manually etc etc. Therefore this solution is not feasible.